# How can I optimise this recursive file size function?

Tags: python, recursion, ftp

I wrote a script that sums the size of the files in subdirectories on a FTP server:

```
for dirs in ftp.nlst("."):
    try:
        print("Searching in "+dirs+"...")
        ftp.cwd(dirs)
        for files in ftp.nlst("."):
                size += ftp.size(files)
        ftp.cwd("../")
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        pass
print("Total size of "+serveradd+tvt+" = "+str(size*10**-9)+" GB")
```

Is there a quicker way to get the size of the whole directory tree other than summing the file sizes for all directories?

Comment: I was the original poster. I was just wondering if there was any way of optimising it. For a directory size of 300 GB it takes 5 minutes to complete. However the unix command 'du -h' completes instantly to print the total directory size.

Comment: Are you strictly limited to FTP as opposed to SSH?

Comment: I believe so...

Comment: This isn't recursive: you haven't defined a function. It'll only go one level down. Also you can definitely save time by leaving out the `cwd` commands and specifying the paths in the other commands.

Comment: Sorry, only started learning python last week, still getting to grips with the nomenclature. Thanks for the cwd tip. I'm not sure it's going to save that much time however (the time taken to change directories is orders of magnitude lower that the time it takes to sum the file sizes in that directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex Hall commented, this is not recursive. I'll address the speeding-up issue, as you can read about recursion from many sources, for example [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion).
Putting that aside, you didn't mention how many files are approximately in that directory, but you're wasting time by spending a whole round-trip for every file in the directory. Instead ask the server to return the entire listing for the directory and sum the file sizes:

```
import re

class DirSizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0

    def add_list_entry(self, lst):
        if '<DIR>' not in lst:
            metadata = re.split(r'\s+', lst)
            self.size += int(metadata[2])

ds = DirSizer()
ftp.retrlines('LIST', ds.add_list_entry)  # add_list_entry will be called for every line
print(ds.size)  # => size (shallow, currently) of the directory
```

Note that:

- This should of course be done recursively for every directory in the tree.
- Your server might return the list in a different format, so you might need to change either the `re.split` line or the `metadata[2]` part.
- If your server supports the MLSD FTP command, use that instead, as it'll be in a standardized format.
- [See here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) for an explanation of `retrlines` and the callback.